# MakeFile can't run command 'rm'

Tags: makefile

I made this MakeFile for a project in C lang:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -std=c99 -g
LDFLAGS = -g
SRC = ${wildcard src/*.c}
HDR = ${wildcard include/*.h}
OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}
EXEC = reaper

all: ${SRC} ${OBJ} ${EXEC}

${EXEC}: ${OBJ}
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c ${HDR}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} $< -o $@

clean:
    rm src/*.o ${EXEC}.exe
```

when I run make clean gives me this Error:

```
rm src/*.o reaper.exe
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm src/*.o reaper.exe, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. 
make: *** [Makefile:18: clean] Error 2
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: When you are running on Windows you should be sure to say that: make is a POSIX/UNIX utility and unless otherwise specified most people will assume you're running on a GNU/Linux or MacOS system.  Your problem is that `rm` is a POSIX utility and so it isn't present on Windows.  You will either need to change your makefile to use Windows utilities like `del` etc. or else install POSIX tools, via cygwin or some other way.